# Julia regular expression \w+/g

Tags: julia

I'm using replace function with regular expression to find all non alphanumeric characters in string.

```
new = replace(cont, r"\w+/g" => "")
```

However, above code do nothing with a string.

If I remove "/g" it works, and it removes all words.

Answer (score 4):

The `/g` part is not needed because by default `replace` replaces all matches of a pattern. If you wanted to e.g. replace one match pass `count=1` keyword argument to `replace`.

Now, in most regular expression parsers `/g` would be an invalid sequence, but in Julia it is accepted, and just matches `/g` verbatim, see:

```
julia> match(r"\w+/g", "##abc/gab##")
RegexMatch("abc/g")

julia> replace("##abc/gab##", r"\w+/g" => "")
"##ab##"
```

as is explained [here](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlre#Modifiers) the `/g` flag in e.g. Perl can be found at the end of regular expression constructs, but is not a generic regular expression flag, but applies to the operation being performed.

In Julia the allowed flags for regex are listed [here](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/strings/#man-regex-literals) and they are `i`, `m`, `s`, and `x` and are suffixed after the regular expression, e.g. `r"a+.*b+.*?d$"ism`.